# javascript closure with a settimeout function

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

How can I express this within a closure with a settimeout function to create a 2 second pause before or after running the API. Note that geocoder.geocode is asynchronous.

```
function srPerformGeocode(addressToArray, nextRecord){                             

        var address = addressToArray.join(",");
        console.log(address);                    

        if (geocoder){                                                   
            glDelay = true;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address.trim() }, function
            (results, status) {
                // count number of geocodings attempted
                glGeocodeCount ++;                                                       
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){            
                }
                else{
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Why: when calling third party API's repeatedly, it is polite to throttle requests, sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout (function ()
{
    geocoder.geocode( ... );

}, 2000);
```

Comment: I tried variations of this. When called repeatedly, it only seems to work the first time the function gets called. Subsequent calls the daly seem to be ignored.

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge: You need to show us the code that is not working. I would even place a bet right now that you have fallen into the `setTimeout( myFunction(), 200)` trap (or similar)